# What problems might I run into in a program with multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Let's say I have two threads that both have access to the same gameWorld instance. The gameWorld has a List and the threads can change affect the entities with the method doAction(Action action, Map values). Each entity has a Map of values. Depending on the action and values put into the doAction method, the entities will be changed in different ways.

Assuming the doAction method is the only way the list of entities can be changed, are there any problems I might run into? What would happen if the same entity is being changed at the same time by both threads? Can multiple methods be running at the same time on one instance? If so, could the same method be running twice at the same time?

Comment: [Concurrency](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm), [Deadlock](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_deadlock.htm), to name a few.

Comment: Second things might occur in an order you don't expect. First programming with threads requires that you consider synchronization of your shared fields.

Comment: Re: "...changed at the same time by both threads."  Say you have an `int i=0;`, and thread A sets `i=1;` thread B sets `i=2;`, and thread C calls `System.out.println(i);` If there's no _synchronization_ between the threads, then you have a _race condition_: There's no way to predict whether thread C will print `0`, `1`, or `2`.

Comment: Also, suppose your "entity" is described by several different fields, and suppose that there are some important relationships between the fields that must be preserved. Even if you have only _one_ thread updating the entity, it has to update the fields one-by-one.  If there's no synchronization between threads, some other thread could look at the entity and see it in a half-changed state---maybe an _invalid_ or non-sensical half-changed state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many issues that can be caused by this.
Below is a list of some: *(this is not every one since there are so many)*

- Concurrency - When you 'concurrently' access a field on several threads.
  Further reading: https://www.callicoder.com/java-concurrency-issues-and-thread- 
  synchronization/

  ---
- Deadlock - When two threads are blocks waiting for each other.
  Further reading: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_deadlock.htm

  ---
- Synchronisation - When two threads are modifying a field or calling a method and they cannot keep up with each other and some modifications will not be recorded. 
  Example:
  If I run the following code, we would want the final printed total to be 2000000 since each thread should add 1000000.

```java
static int total = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            total++;
            System.out.println("Thread 1 added! New total: " + total);
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            total++;
            System.out.println("Thread 2 added! New total: " + total);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

However, the last few lines of the console are as follows:

```
Thread 2 added! New total: 199996
Thread 2 added! New total: 199997
Thread 2 added! New total: 199998
```

As we can see, this is an unacceptable result. 
This is however simply fixed with the `synchronised` keyword.
If we run this, we get a result of 2000000 as we wanted.

```java
static int total = 0;
static synchronized void add() {
    total++;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            add();
            System.out.println("Thread 1 added! New total: " + total);
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(() -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            add();
            System.out.println("Thread 2 added! New total: " + total);
        }
    }).start();
}
```